# Is there a specific way to read POST data from wpforms?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, session

I'm trying to access form data entered by the user on a form created with wpforms and save them as session variables, but no matter what I try, I can't seem to get anything from the form. I can hardcode the information into the session variables, and they work as expected, but it needs to pull the data from the form.

Here's the snippet from the php code I have on the page:

```
<?php
echo session_id();
$_SESSION['age'] = $_POST['wpforms[fields][3]'];
$_SESSION['gender'] = $_POST['wpforms[fields][2]'];
?>
```

I've also included some code from the second page once the form has been submitted, which is where I see that the session variables are set correctly when I hard code them in the first page, but not set when I try to pull from the form.

```
echo session_id();
if ( isset($_SESSION['gender'])) {
echo "Gender is  set.<br>";
}
else {
echo "Gender not set<br>";
}
if ( isset($_SESSION['age'])) {
echo "Age is set.<br>";
}
else {
echo "Age not set.<br>";
}
echo $_SESSION['gender'];
echo $_SESSION['age'];
```

Any insight will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!
[Screenshot of page inspection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiSxe.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I had to add the following code to my functions.php file on the wordpress theme I was using:

```
add_action('init', 'register_my_session');
function register_my_session() {
    if (!session_id() ) {
        session_start();
        }
function wpf_dev_process_entry_save( $fields, $entry, $form_id, $form_data ) {
    // Only run on my form with ID = 4117
    if ( absint( $form_data['id'] ) !== 4117 ) {
            return $fields;
        } 
    $_SESSION['age'] = $fields[3]['value']; // This is where we access the form data
    $_SESSION['gender'] = $fields[2]['value'];
}
add_action( 'wpforms_process_entry_save', 'wpf_dev_process_entry_save', 10, 4 );
    }
```

Comment: i have tried the same but it's not working for me